# Using the each operator with the without function in APL

Tags: arrays, map-function, apl, set-difference, dyalog

I have a nested array with the following data:

```
┌→────────────────┐
│ ┌→────┐ ┌→────┐ │
│ │ABC12│ │DEF34│ │
│ └─────┘ └─────┘ │
└∊────────────────┘
```

I would like to remove the numbers from each, so that it looks like this:

```
┌→────────────┐
│ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │ABC│ │DEF│ │
│ └───┘ └───┘ │
└∊────────────┘
```

I tried using the without function (~) with the each operator (¨) and a right argument of '0123456789' but I get a length error. I also tried putting each number in its own array like this:

```
┌→────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ ┌→┐ │
│ │0│ │1│ │2│ │3│ │4│ │5│ │6│ │7│ │8│ │9│ │
│ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ └─┘ │
└∊────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

but this too resulted in a length error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Dyalog APL, you could try a direct-function that removes digits (`⎕D`) from strings, applied to each string in your array, e.g.

```
      yourData
┌→────────────────┐
│ ┌→────┐ ┌→────┐ │
│ │ABC12│ │DEF34│ │
│ └─────┘ └─────┘ │
└∊────────────────┘
      {⍵~⎕D}¨yourData
┌→────────────┐
│ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │ABC│ │DEF│ │
│ └───┘ └───┘ │
└∊────────────┘
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is set-subtracting ("without-ing") the *entire* set of digits (`⎕D`) from each. So we enclose the digit set to act on it as a whole:

```
      'ABC12' 'DEF34'~¨⊂⎕D
┌→────────────┐
│ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │ABC│ │DEF│ │
│ └───┘ └───┘ │
└∊────────────┘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HvXIWQjMxiheT8lFQFIJ1aWJpZlpiTmleiUJKvEJuUX6GQn6egW1xSmZNqm5tYwaWekllckJNYqf6ob6pzpHpKWl6xOpfLo7YJ1UABIAWVftS7q5YLKBLsCiTCg9Vdy4BGqiuoB6cWF2fm5wUUZYK5Lur//6s7OjkbGoE4rm7GJup1h1Y86moC6nIBAA)

Notice how this very much reads like what you want:

> Your data (`'ABC12' 'DEF34'`) without (`~`) each (`¨`) of the whole (`⊂`) set of digits (`⎕D`).